# Error Mixin : Abstract classes cannot be instantiated in Dart

Tags: dart

I was learning dart but it was still an error when I entered into the mixin, I don't know the fault where it is always an error when:

Abstract classes cannot be instantiated

I want to implement a mixin for Cat, Elang and Hiu with a subclass of Mamalia, Burung, Ikan

This is the [Github code](https://github.com/ihsandroid1/error-mixin-dart):

Answer (score 1):

The error are rather clear. You cannot make an instance of an abstract class since an abstract class per definition is a class which can define methods and fields which are yet to be implemented and the class is therefore not complete.

The purpose of abstract classes is to let other classes extend from them and implement the missing methods.

I don't know why all your classes are marked as `abstract` but you can just remove the `abstract` keyword from the classes: `Mamalia`, `Ikan` and `Burung` and it should work since all of these classes are not needed to be `abstract`.

Comment: i tried but still didn't get it, could you give me some example in main.dart? thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

[Abstract Class](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#abstract-classes) -

> Use the abstract modifier to define an abstract class—a class that can’t be instantiated. Abstract classes are useful for defining interfaces, often with some implementation.

Don't instantiate `Mamalia`, `Burung` or `Ikan` classes. Instead instantiate  `Cat`, `Elang` and `Hiu`.

```
Mamlia mamal = Cat(); // Will allow accessing methods defined only in Mamal class
Cat cat = Cat() // Will allow accessing all the methods defined in Cat class
```

Comment: i tried this and error message is the function can't defined, i write like this :                 
import 'Mamalia.dart';
import 'Burung.dart';
import 'Ikan.dart';

void main(){

Mamalia mamal = Cat();
Burung burung = Elang();
Ikan ikan = Hiu();
}